# Microservices decomposition strategy

Tags: microservices, decomposition, bounded-contexts

I have a monolith which I'm trying to decompose into microservices. However the **microservices will not have much logic**, except consuming a source system API and  enriching the response with some additional static data. What would be the best strategy in the following 2 scenarios?

**Scenario 1**

[image]

- There are multiple source systems
- Each functional area consumes a distinct API of one of the source systems

What should be the best decomposition approach? Microservice per functional area (4) or microservice per source system (2)?

**Scenario 2**

[image]

- A single source system which exposes a single API
- Each functional area consumes the same source system API with different parameters.

What should be the best decomposition approach? Microservice per functional area (4) or microservice per source API (single microservice) ?

**Update**

- No enrichment of payload is required.
- Dash-line indicates the system boundary

Comment: For enriching the response, how is that done? Is that done by going to another data source to enrich it or is it transforming the data set that comes back from the API originally? Also, it may help to actually have a little more context on the domain boundaries. The in itself actually helps a lot when it comes to deciding one microservice or multiple microservice.

Comment: Single microservice is the better approach to my opinion. I recommend reading the entire book dedicated to this called "Building Microservices: Designing Fine-Grained Systems" from Sam Newman.